# Allow user to access wordpress blog only from a specific URL using htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I run a wordpress blog. I want my blog to be available only for those users who come from a particular website only. Other users who type URL of my blog in the browser should not be able to access my blog.

The idea behind putting that restriction is that only registered users of that particular website can access the blog. There would a link of my blog on that particular website, which only registered users can see, click and access.

And both the sites i.e. that particular website and my wordpress blog are hosted on the same server.

I am using following code in wordpress .htaccess file.

```
<Files index.php>
order allow,deny
allow from abcd.com/moodle
deny from all
</Files>
```

facing:  Internal Server Error

Looking forward to get a prompt reply.

Thanks in advance!

Regards,
Dinesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check the referer, you can use this :

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer "^http://abcd\.com/moodle" checkreferer
Order deny,allow
Allow from env=checkreferer
Deny from all
```

You can also use mod_rewrite with a RewriteCond on the referer.

And be aware that referer can be faked.